# How to use AND in THEN part of a SQL CASE Statement with different header names

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a requirement in a `SQL View` where I need to check a condition, and if it's true, I need to update two column values and both these columns need to have custom header names.

I assumed `CASE` would work here but I am not sure how to implement this.

For example,

```
CASE WHEN A2016.OpExp IS NULL THEN A2015.OpExp ELSE A2016.OpExp END AS 'OPEX'
```

Here, when A.2016 is null, in the THEN part I want **A2015.OpExp AS 'OPEX' AND A.Year = 2015 AS 'Year'**.

Please also advice if my decision to use `CASE` in this situation wrong.

Comment: how about adding your table schemas and the query you have tried?

Comment: what do you mean by "custom header names"?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please show some sample table data and the expected result.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. By custom header I meant the name given to a column using AS clause. Usually this is given after ending CASE statement but in my situation I need it for each of the columns.

Comment: In this instance it looks like [`Coalesce`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql) will meet your needs: `Coalesce( A2016.OpExp, A2015.OpExp ) as [OpEx]`. The second column (`[Year]`) is gracefully handled in Y. Ecarri's answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are TWO possible syntaxes for CASE WHEN THEN END:

```
CASE variable
    WHEN value1 then result1
    WHEN value2 then result2...
END
```

and

```
CASE 
   WHEN condition THEN value1
   WHEN othercondition then value2...
END
```

The second one accepts "AND" as part of the condition, for example

```
CASE
   WHEN X = 0 AND Y = 0 THEN 'On the origin'
   WHEN X = 0 AND Y <> 0 THEN 'On the X axis'
   WHEN X <> 0 AND Y = 0 THEN 'On the Y axis'
   ELSE 'Somewhere over the rainbow'
END
```

None of the syntaxes allow you to do what you intend.

There are several ways to achieve what you need. One way is using TWO field expressions, one for OPEX and one for YEAR, like this:

```
CASE WHEN A2016.OpExp Is Null then A2015.OpExp ELSE A2016.OpExp END as OPEX,
CASE WHEN A2016.OpExp Is Null then 2015 ELSE 2016 END as YEAR...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "custom header" means the column alias (`AS` clause), you cannot change that dynamically in the view. View column names and data type meta data are determined when the view is created. The returned values may differ conditionally, as you have done with the `CASE` expression.